# Physical reads caused by WITH clause

Tags: sql, oracle11g, query-optimization

I have a set of complex optimized selects that suffer from physical reads. Without them they would be even faster!

These physical reads occur due to the WITH clause, one physical_read_request per WITH sub-query. They seem totally unnecessary to me, I'd prefer Oracle keeping the sub-query results in memory instead of writing them down to disk and reading them again.

I'm looking for a way how to get rid of these phys reads.

A simple sample having the same problems is this:

**Edit:** Example replaced with simpler one that does not use dictionary views.

```
alter session set STATISTICS_LEVEL=ALL;

create table T as
select level NUM from dual
connect by level <= 1000;

with /*a2*/ TT as (
    select NUM from T
    where NUM between 100 and 110
  )
select * from TT 
union all
select * from TT
;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(
  (select sql_id from v$sql
   where sql_fulltext like 'with /*a2*/ TT%'
     and sql_fulltext not like '%v$sql%'
     and sql_fulltext not like 'explain%'),
  NULL, format=>'allstats last'));
```

and the corresponding execution plan is

```
SQL_ID  bpqnhfdmxnqvp, child number 0
-------------------------------------
with /*a2*/ TT as (     select NUM from T     where NUM between 100 and 
110   ) select * from TT  union all select * from TT

Plan hash value: 4255080040

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name                      | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  | Writes |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |                           |      1 |        |     22 |00:00:00.01 |      20 |      1 |      1 |       |       |          |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION |                           |      1 |        |     22 |00:00:00.01 |      20 |      1 |      1 |       |       |          |
|   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT           |                           |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       8 |      0 |      1 |   266K|   266K|  266K (0)|
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL       | T                         |      1 |     11 |     11 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |      0 |      0 |       |       |          |
|   4 |   UNION-ALL                |                           |      1 |        |     22 |00:00:00.01 |       9 |      1 |      0 |       |       |          |
|   5 |    VIEW                    |                           |      1 |     11 |     11 |00:00:00.01 |       6 |      1 |      0 |       |       |          |
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6646_63A776 |      1 |     11 |     11 |00:00:00.01 |       6 |      1 |      0 |       |       |          |
|   7 |    VIEW                    |                           |      1 |     11 |     11 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |      0 |      0 |       |       |          |
|   8 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6646_63A776 |      1 |     11 |     11 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |      0 |      0 |       |       |          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter(("NUM">=100 AND "NUM"<=110))

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

See the (phys) Write upon each WITH view creation, and the (phys) Read upon the first view usage. I also tried the RESULT_CACHE hint (which is not reflected in this sample select, but was reflected in my original queries), but it doesn't remove the disk accesses either (which is understandable).

How can I get rid of the phys writes/reads?

Comment: Why do you think each (or any) `with` is doing any disk writes? There is only one write shown for the whole statement. And you can't retrieve data without reading from disk - or at least the buffer cache - at some point. There is the `/*+ materialized */` hint but it isn't clear you need it. Using a dictionary view as an example isn't really useful as it is doing all sorts of under-the-hood stuff. A real query might make more sense. Trying to diganose a performance issue in one query from the plan/stats from a completely unrelated one isn't likely to get you very far.

Comment: I'm not claiming that any WITH causes disk writes, e.g. this one does not do that: `with x as (select * from dual) select * from x;` However I found a few more complicated selects that cause the disk operations even when the WITH sub-selects return only a few rows. And them I am discussing. I'll try to create an even simpler example without using dictionary views, but I'd say that if one succeeds in solving the problem for one such select, it would work for most of them.

Comment: I discussed the problem in Oracle forums, https://community.oracle.com/thread/3564139, but without successful result.